# If array of players is empty, then echo "No Players Online"

Tags: php, list

I want it so that if there are players in the array, it will return with the pictures. That works so far. What doesn't work is that when no players are in the array, it will return a blank picture and will not echo `"No Players Online"`.

```
$query = (Minequery::query("67.202.102.224"));
$plist = $query['playerList'];
foreach($plist as $k => $v)
    // print_r(Minequery::query_json("67.202.102.224"));
    if (defined($plist)){
        echo'<img src="http://minotar.net/avatar/'.$v.'" title="'.$v.'" height="50"     width="50">  '; 
    } else {
        echo 'No Players Online';
    }
```

Comment: Use `!empty()` rather than `defined()`

Comment: Is this the PHP library you're using? https://github.com/vexsoftware/minequery-php

Comment: Yes it is. I'm just outputting a player list, and if it comes back empty, I just want it to say No Players Online

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You kinda have your cart in front of your horse:

```
$query = (Minequery::query("67.202.102.224"));
$plist = $query['playerList'];
foreach($plist as $k => $v)
    //print_r(Minequery::query_json("67.202.102.224"));
    if (defined($plist)){
        echo'<img src="http://minotar.net/avatar/'.$v.'" title="'.$v.'" height="50"            width="50">  ';  
    }
    else {
        echo 'No Players Online';
    }
```

You're checking to see if the array has content AFTER you've started trying to iterate through it. Try this:

```
$query = (Minequery::query("67.202.102.224"));
$plist = $query['playerList'];
if (!empty($plist)) {
    foreach($plist as $k => $v) {
        echo '<img src="http://minotar.net/avatar/'.$v.'" title="'.$v.'" height="50" width="50">  ';  
    }
}
else {
    echo 'No Players Online';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An empty array (e.g. `array()`) equals `false`, that means with a simple if-clause you can handle that:

```
if ($plist) {
    echo '<img src="http://minotar.net/avatar/'.$v.'" title="'.$v.'" height="50" width="50"> ';  
} else {
    echo 'No Players Online ';
}
```

However, you need to check that before you loop over it:

```
if (!$plist) {
    echo 'No Players Online';
} else {
    foreach($plist as $k => $v) {
        echo '<img src="http://minotar.net/avatar/'.$v.'" title="'.$v.'" height="50" width="50">';
    }
}
```

> **Note:** You need the latest version of [minequery-php](https://github.com/vexsoftware/minequery-php) to have this properly working. There was a bug that has been fixed. now.

Take care as well that `$v` should be properly encoded if you use it inside HTML - not that the it contains HTML and then your intended HTML gets broken. See [`htmlspecialchars`](http://de.php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Similar for the URL you use it into, if you do not properly URL-encode it, the URL might get broken. See [`urlencode`](http://de.php.net/urlencode).

Comment: I have no clue why...But still no working solution. When there is no players online it still will just show an empty picture, and wont show No Players Online. I've tried all solutions =/

Comment: Okay, do a `echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars(print_r($plist, 1)), '</pre>';` *before* the if and tell what the output is. Probably there is just an empty value inside the array, so the array isn't technically empty.

Comment: Consider using `var_dump` instead of `print_r`. And you need to view source then.

Comment: It comes back with: array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } int(1)

Comment: As I assumed, it is not empty. It looks like that this is a flaw within the PHP class. You should file a bug-report pointing to here. The flaw is invalid input sanitization that class does. Instead use the `json_query` it should not have that flaw.

Comment: Alrighty, Thanks for the help, and now I got some more tricks in my PHP arsenal :D

Comment: Yay :) - I also reported the error with that class and the original author told that minequery is obsolete for some time now. You *might* (I don't know) want to use the new method. The pull request is here: [minequery-php - Demonstrate that no players lead to error.](https://github.com/vexsoftware/minequery-php/pull/5) - it's already fixed, so if you take the latest version the problem should be gone and it should work as outlined in my answer.